# Reduce Number of Color Variables SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have a huge list of colors for my scss generation. I would LOVE to to find a way to generate codes that would simplify this. These colors were selected by a web designer, but he didn't use the built in scss hue/tint/shade modifiers. Are there any tools that could take my list and simplify them so that I only have a handful of names to look for?

```
//*--------Color Variables--------*//
$alto-1: #dadada;
$alto-2: #dddddd;
$anakiwa: #99eaff;
$athens-gray: #f5f7f9;
$black-rgb: rgb(0, 0 ,0);
$black: #000000;
$blue_zodiac: #113355;
$candlelight: #ffdd22;
$casper-hex: #a9bbc9;
$casper: rgb(173, 186, 188);
$cinnabar: #e3451b;
$cocoa_brown: #332222;
$cod_gray: #111111;
$cornflower_blue: #68b0e7;
$curious_blue-1: #308ade;
$curious_blue-2: #2b82d3;
$curious_blue-3: #189ee7;
$danube: #75a6d4;
$dark_tan: #661111;
$demin-rgb: rgb(20, 120, 160);
$denim-1: #1144cc;
$denim-2: #1571c6;
$denim-3: #1576d4;
$denim-4: #136ec2;
$denim-5: #0a60c0;
$dodger_blue: #21b1ff;
$dove_gray: #666666;
$gallery: #eeeeee;
$geyser: #dae1e5;
$green: #008000;
$grenadier: #e03004;
$light_grey: #d3d3d3;
$lily_white: #e7faff;
$link_water: #c7def1;
$lochmara-1: #0482da;
$lochmara-2: #0a79c9;
$mabel: #d9f7ff;
$mariner: #2368b5;
$maroon: #770000;
$matisse: #195b9a;
$mine_shaft-1: #222222;
$mine_shaft-2: #333333;
$mortar: rgb(90, 90, 90);
$mountain_meadow: #16AE61;
$night_rider: rgb(50, 50, 50);
$onahau-1: #c4e8ff;
$onahau-2: #beefff;
$onahau-3: #c9faff;
$onahau-rgb: rgb(200, 220, 240);
$patterns_blue: #ddeeff;
$pomegranate-1: #e74c18;
$pomegranate-2: #F74C18;
$pomegranate-3: #ee3322;
$prussian_blue-1: rgb(0, 40, 80);
$prussian_blue-2: rgb(0, 20, 60);
$punch: #dd3333;
$red-hex: #ff0000;
$red: rgb(245, 10, 10);
$regent_st_blue: #a7cde4;
$rhino: #253a4d;
$science_blue: #0561b9;
$silver-1: #cccccc;
$silver-2: #cacaca;
$silver_chalice: #aaaaaa;
$summer_sky: rgb(77, 177, 219);
$thunderbird: #cc1111;
$transparent: transparent;
$twilight_blue: #f0fdff;
$white-rgb: rgb(255, 255, 255);
$white: #ffffff;
```

Comment: I forked a github repo and added the ability to type in a hex as well as use the color picker.  You would have to grab the code and modify the default color list, but it might help you.  https://dmikester1.github.io/nearest-color/

Comment: I can use this in combination with a tool located at http://razorltd.github.io/sasscolourfunctioncalculator/